# criteria to return correct results not working in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to only show the yellow results below? Using sql server I've tried doing `where provider_name = previous_discharge_prov or previous_discharge_prov is null` but it returns row _num 1 and 3 for cust_id 120343796 instead of 2 and 3. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Telling us the logic behind what "SHOW" and "DON'T SHOW" is would help us hep you.

Comment: As for what you attempted, what you got back was correct for that `WHERE`. For `120343796` when `ROW_NUM` has the value `2`, `provider_name` and `previous_discharge_prov` have different values, and neither are `NULL`; so they don't been the requirement. Also the first row would have been returned with that `WHERE`, but you don't want that either. Without you expressing the logic you need, it's difficult for us to know what you want (and if you don't know, what hope do we have?).

Comment: i did a separate cte with just cust_id and sum(row_num) where provider_name = previous_discharge_prov then joined that to the last query from above to remove the cust_id with just row_num = 1. What logic would I need to show find what I was asking?

Comment: You need to explain how you determine which rows you want to show or not.

Comment: I want to show the cust_id that were discharged to the same provider_name.

Comment: The same provider as "what"?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The cust_id has a provider_name and admit/discharge date. I need to show the cust_id's who were admitted consecutively to the same provider. Like the first five rows of cust_id 1394930.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is very unclear here, however, at a guess based on your comment *"I need to show the cust_id's who were admitted consecutively to the same provider"* perhaps you mean this:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {Your Needed Columns},
           LAG(ProviderName) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY RowNum) AS PreviousProvider,
           LEAD(ProviderName) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY RowNum) AS NextProvider
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT {Your Needed Columns}
FROM CTE
WHERE ProviderName IN (PreviousProvider,NextProvider);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explaining it well. I think that is it. Thank you for being patient and for the help. Much appreciated.